# Sorting a python array

Tags: python, sorting

```
opt=[]
opt=["opt3","opt2","opt7","opt6","opt1"]
for i in range(len(opt)):
     print opt[i]
```

Output for the above is

```
opt3,opt2,opt7,opt6,opt1
```

How to sort the above array in ascending order..

Comment: `for i in range(len(opt))` is unPythonic. Use `for elt in opt` instead.

Comment: You do not need the first line (`opt=[]`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`.sort()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) if you want to sort the original list. (`opt.sort()`)

Use [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) if you want a sorted copy of it.

Answer (score 2):

`print sorted(opt)`

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether or not you want a natural sort (which I think you do) or not.

If you use `sorted()` or `.sort()` you'll get:

```
>>> opt = ["opt3", "opt2", "opt7", "opt6", "opt1", "opt10", "opt11"]
>>> print sorted(opt)
['opt1', 'opt10', 'opt11', 'opt2', 'opt3', 'opt6', 'opt7']
```

While you'll probably want `['opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3', 'opt6', 'opt7', 'opt10', 'opt11']`.

If so you'll want to look into [natural sorting](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html) (there are various variations on the function mentioned in that article).